# Validating a System.Uri used as an input to an API call

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have an API written in ASP.NET Core 7. This API is intended to be called by a very small number of trusted clients. To that end, I use a shared secret to authenticate the caller. But that authentication, like any authentication, may be compromised, leading to calls from a malicious client.

My API includes a "register new user" endpoint that accepts a POST request containing the new user's username (their email address), password, and a "callback" URL. Assuming the API can successfully create a new user with the specified username and password, the API sends an email to the new user with a "confirmation" link that the user must follow to verify the email address.

The confirmation link consists of the "callback" URL supplied in the POST request plus a confirmation token appended to that URL as a URL query parameter.

The applicable code looks kind of like this:

```
public class RegisterUserResource
{
    public required string Email { get; set; }
    public required string Password { get; set; }
    public required Uri CallbackUrl { get; set; }
}

public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult RegisterNewUser([FromBody] RegisterUserResource resource)
    {
        // Validate the caller-supplied URL
        var url = resource.CallbackUrl;
        if (url == null) return BadRequest();
        if (!url.IsAbsoluteUri) return BadRequest();
        if (url.IsFile) return BadRequest();

        // Register the new user and send the email
        <...>

        // Done
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

In the above code, the model binder constructs a `System.Uri` from the `callbackUrl` property in the JSON data contained in the body of the POST request.

Now, I want to perform some tests on that `System.Uri` to try to verify that it is something the user can safely navigate to. In the sample code, I verify that the model binder was at least able to construct an absolute URI from the caller-supplied data, and that URI doesn't try to download a file.

**My question is: What tests do I want to perform against the `Uri` to try to protect against malicious or simply invalid URLs?**

(And now that I'm thinking about it... I could compare the host portion of the URL against a list of known valid callers - remember I said this API should only be called from a small number of trusted callers, and I know their domain (host) names. But hardcoding host names into the code, or pulling them out of a database, just smells wrong... but I guess it doesn't smell any worse than somehow generating, storing, and retrieving the "shared secret" I use to authenticate the caller.)

Comment: Sounds like Identity Emial confirm? have you verified  before you generate the security token?

Comment: @RuikaiFeng Have I verified what? (Yes, the confirmation link includes an Identity confirmation token.)